# Change block titles from h2 to h3

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

I want that block titles have the h3 tag instead the h2 tag. As I understand I have to change this in the file block.tpl.php.
I found 4 block.tpl.php

- root/modules/block/
- sites/all/themes/omega/omega/templates
- sites/all/themes/omega/starterkits/omega-xhtml/templates
- sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/templates/

My question: Which one is the right file to change? I took now the one in the omega folder and it worked (the one in the modules folder did not). But I want to be sure whether this is the correct in order not to have side effects.
And what for is the modules/block directory with files?

thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 6):

As a rule, we should never make changes in core files. If you will read the readme.md file in omega theme, you will see the following,

> Omega 4.x is a base theme and as such should **never** be used or
>   modified directly. Instead, you should use the [sub-theming
>   functionality](https://drupal.org/node/225125) provided by Drupal.
>
> The easiest way to create a new Omega-based sub-theme is by using
>   [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush). Omega comes with a very
>   easy-to-use Drush command for generating sub-themes through a
>   command-line wizard. You can start the sub-theme creation wizard by
>   invoking `drush omega-wizard` in the command-line.

So you should first create omega sub-theme which is quite easy process and then make changes in sub-theme's block.tpl.php file.

Comment: thanks to both of you for the fast answers. I am not a programmer, but understood what has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal gives you really easy ways to override core functionality, including themes and modules. In your case, the best thing you can do is to create a sub-theme for your Omega theme.

A sub-theme is basically a theme that inherits functionality from a parent theme. Follow the instructions from here: [Creating a sub-theme](https://drupal.org/node/225125)

Once you've done that, you can manually copy those files from the parent theme into your sub-theme, to override them, and change them as much as you want.